# Why does this _bstr_t corrupt the heap?

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, memory-leaks, msxml, heap-corruption

The below code is used as part of a larger MSXML parsing project.  I recently switched from Visual Studio 2008 to Visual Studio 2015.  This method gets used repeatedly in many places.  In VS2008 there was no crashing.  In VS2015 it only crashes in one spot but it always crashes in that same spot.

The 'fix' I added is near the bottom, "**bstrXpath.Assign(NULL);**" and I'm worried that I should be doing something differently.  Why is the heap corrupted by one _bstr_t and not the other 2?  The only difference is that value is getting passed in.

I'm not sure if it makes a difference, but the only value that caused the corruption is when pInXmlFile was set to L"medianame/medianame_item[@language='EN']" and, of course, that memory is on the heap.

```
HRESULT GetSelectNode(MSXML2::IXMLDOMNode **ppOutXMLDomSelectNode, const wchar_t *pInXmlFilePath, const wchar_t *pInXpath)
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    _bstr_t bstrXpath = SysAllocString(pInXpath);
    _bstr_t bstrPropertyNameLang = SysAllocString(L"SelectionLanguage");
    _bstr_t bstrPropertyNameNameSpace = SysAllocString(L"SelectionNamespaces");
    VARIANT_BOOL varbResult;
    CComVariant vPath(pInXmlFilePath);
    CComVariant vXPath("XPath");
    CComVariant vIvecNamespace(IVEC_CMD_NAMESPACE_TEXT);

    MSXML2::IXMLDOMDocument2Ptr pXMLDoc = NULL;
    hr = pXMLDoc.CreateInstance(__uuidof(DOMDocument60));

    //... Do stuff with the variables above, checking for errors and stuff.

    pXMLDoc.Release();
    SysFreeString(bstrXpath);
    bstrXpath.Assign(NULL);
    SysFreeString(bstrPropertyNameLang);
    SysFreeString(bstrPropertyNameNameSpace);

    return hr;
}
```

This is production code.  I just spent the last day or so debugging with little success, but someone on here suggested using the .Assign(NULL) in a very old post that seemed unrelated to this question.  So that's what I tried and I don't know why it worked.

I am not an expert at MSXML but it is no longer a choice.  This is source code from my parent corporation and I'm trying to plug memory leaks.  And nobody I work with has ever messed with either MSXML or _bstr_t.

More details:  The actual crashing in VS2015 happens on the last line "return hr;" deep in the callstack in comutil.c _Free() method.  The two hard-coded strings are de-allocated without error but the bstrXpath throws the error.  (Adding that line to the 2008 code it does seem like it fixed a memory leak.)

Comment: `_bstr_t bstrXpath = SysAllocString(pInXpath);` This leaks. You allocate a `BSTR` with `SysAllocString`, but `_bstr_t` constructor you use assumes it's a plain `wchar_t*` and allocates its own `BSTR`. Make it `_bstr_t bstrXpath(pInXpath);`

Comment: `SysFreeString(bstrXpath);` This leads to double destruction. `_bstr_t` makes its own `SysFreeString` call in its destructor, on the same `BSTR`. That's likely the immediate cause of your problem. Drop all `SysAllocString` and `SysFreeString` calls - the whole point of using smart wrappers like `_bstr_t` is to avoid manual memory management.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik  You solved my final memory leak.  I applied this to the rest of the class and the leaks are gone.  Thank you so much!